# Query SQL somar campos de uma tabela com critério de outra

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Gostaria de fazer uma query que somasse por exemplo o nome das pessoas iguais por data (aqui eu vou colocar o período, por exemplo de `01/03` a `22/03`), o problema que tenho duas tabelas, uma de indivíduos onde tenho o nome e uma ocorrências onde eu tenha a data, porém não estou conseguindo exito nas minhas tentativas.
Tentei algo abaixo, porém não deu muito certo:

```
select COUNT(*), individuos.nome, ocorrencias.data_comunicacao  
from ocorrencias, individuos  
group by individuos.nome
```

Comment: Há alum relacionamento entre as tabelas?

Comment: Tem o id_ocorrencia_ind na tabela individuos que é chave estrangeira da tabela ocorrencias. Ligação 0..N

Comment: @MarceloC.França aprove a resposta marcando ✓ se ela estiver correta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça o where relacionando as tabelas conforme abaixo

```
select COUNT(*), individuos.nome, ocorrencias.data_comunicacao  
from ocorrencias, individuos  
where individuos .id_ocorrencia_ind  =ocorrencias.id_ocorrencia_ind 
group by individuos.nome
```

Comment: Deu certo Marciano Obrigado!!!